# Using TailwindCSS Forms with Blazor EditForm doesn't remove styling on InputText

Tags: blazor, tailwind-css, blazor-editform

When using [Tailwind forms](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-forms), I am expecting my `<InputText />` element to be unstyled but it keeps the original styling for the text input.

It works fine if I do something like
`<input type="text" name="client_name" id="client_name" class="block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md">`

How can I take away the built in styling for `<InputText />` when using TailwindCSS-forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add on a `type="text"`.

So you would want something like this:
`<InputText type="text" id="client_name" @bind-Value="client.Name" class="block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md"/>`

The reason being explained below from the @tailwindcss/forms docs:

> Note that for text inputs, you must add the type="text" attribute for these styles to take effect. This is a necessary trade-off to avoid relying on the overly greedy input selector and unintentionally styling elements we don't have solutions for yet, like input[type="range"] for example.